# Solution for this Convolution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-analysis, convex-analysis, convolution

We have $f(z)=z+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$ where $a_{n}$ is a constant and $g(z)=z$, $(f*g)(z)$ is equal to what? i still wondering to confirm that $(f*g)(z)=z$.

Comment: Nothing special about $a_n$?

Comment: @J.M., it just a constant..

Comment: Can you write down a formula for $f*g$?

Comment: Your solution is wrong. If you write out how you got there, someone may be able to tell you where you went wrong. Also, do you literally mean "$a_n$ is a constant" in the singular, or do you mean "the $a_n$ are constants"?

Comment: @joriki: i'm sorry, the $a_{n}$ are constants. how to convolute them since $g(z)=z$ which do not have any series of $a_{n}z_{n}$

Comment: @Norlyda. It is a homework question, or is it your conjecture?